# Ask about Function of "Facebook LIKE button" on a website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook

I have some questions about the function of facebook "like button" on my website. Let's say if I have a free photo website and I want to add a like button to each photo on the page.

QUESTIONS:

1. If there are 5 photos on a html page, and each of them don't have
   specific html page, how can each like button link to a specific
   photo?
2. To hit on Like, people need to login on facebook first right? So if
   they don't login at the moment, how can I link the LIKE button to
   Login via Facebook on my website?
3. I have tried the button code on a test page. It works well on iPad
   and Desktop. But once I clicked like button on my android mobile
   (Sony Xeperia Z2), it links to a broken page.. What is wrong with
   this?

Here is the code I am using:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.testwebsite.com/" data-layout="box_count" 
data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false">
</div>
```

Comment: 1) You need to _create_ an individual URL for each photo. 2) The Like button will ask the user to login automatically, you don’t have to implement anything yourself in that regard.

Comment: @CBroe For an individual URL, is it this one.. `meta property="og:url"           content="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" />
    <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title"         content="Your Website Title" />
    <meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
    <meta property="og:image"         content="http://www.your-domain.com/path/image.jpg" />`

Comment: By the way, I cannot click in Like button, it says "confirm". You can try here http://www.adgroof.com/

Comment: That is a security measure against click-jacking, and can be triggered when you do intensive testing. It just means that you will have to click on “confirm” as well to confirm that you actually intended to like this URL.